# How to Search Instagram caption text?

Tags: api, instagram

Is it possible to search Instagram photo stream posts ( captions ) instead of searching hashtags for certain area . Many people are posting without defining hashtags , and some disable their location , So how to search Media  ' captions ' in the public stream or area stream !

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search

has no search query .

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tag/media/recent

just look for hashtags not the caption text !

Comment: Can you send the original link. Both don't work for me.

Comment: @kiran.koduru didn't add my link , those are Instagram API .

Comment: I am using Meteor & Mongo DB and i managed to search Hashtags and retrieve the media query for certain location as documented in Instagram API . I also managed to perform search for the cached posts's caption ... but i don't know how to search media caption text using API directly as well as dealing with location disabled posts .

Comment: Nevermind I was looking for the endpoints for the API

Answer (score 2):

You can try google search:

"site:instagram.com/p sunset"

Answer (score 1):

Using GraphQL APIs.
Take a look at getAllUserJsonData() function of the IGPF project [here](https://github.com/LucaBarile/InstagramPostFinder).